# How to find the new name of a renamed file in git

Tags: git

I'm looking through git history, and I've found some file of interest. Unfortunately, it's been renamed! Is there a tidy way to discover what the new path to the file is?

My current approach is

```
[dbn repo]$ git log -- -1 --pretty=oneline old_directory/interesting_file.py
5ee1cf move old_directory files
[dbn repo]$ git log --stat -1 5ee1cf
commit 5ee1cf
Author: oh, it was me, the scoundral <dbn@dbn.dbn>

    move old_directory files

{old_directory => new_directory}/interesting_file.py
```

I could collapse this into a one-liner, but the move commit may have a bunch of other stuff in it that I don't care about.

background - I'm doing this manually now, but it's part of some archeology work I'm hoping to script up, so it would be nice to have a solution that could fit in a script.

Comment: `git log --follow`

Comment: That finds old names if I know the new name. I only know the old name.

Comment: Aha! Indeed it seems that it does not work the other way.

Comment: `git diff 5ee1cf^` to see that commit's changes. The `^` means "diff this commit and the one before it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess

# Usage: ./script <file>
file = sys.argv[1]
search_next = True
while search_next:
    sha1 = subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "--format=%H", "-1", "--", file]).rstrip().decode()
    if sha1 == '':
        exit(0)
    file_stat = subprocess.check_output(["git", "whatchanged", "--format=", "-1", sha1]).strip().decode()
    for line in file_stat.splitlines():
        columns = line.split()
        change_type = columns[4]
        old_file = columns[5]
        if change_type.startswith("R") and old_file == file:
            print(f"File ‘{file}’ was renamed to ‘{columns[6]}’ in commit {sha1}")
            file = columns[6]
            search_next = True
            break
        search_next = False
```

`git whatchanged` has less annoying to parse “stat” output.

You can apparently pass git-log(1)’s `-M` switch to git-whatchanged(1)
(i.e. the thing that controls the file difference detection).

[testing](https://pastebin.com/3u51wgg4)

Comment: IMO, avoid scripts when possible. Use `git log` to find the commit, and `git show` to see the patch, including the renamed file

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to do it is

```
git log --oneline -m --first-parent --diff-filter=R --name-status
```

and look through the results for the paths you're interested in.

edit: quickie awk to do the hunting for an optional regex original-path match

```
git log --format=%h -m --first-parent --name-status \
| awk ' NF==1{id=$1} NF==3 && $2~path{print id,$1,$2,$3} ' \
        FS=$'\t' OFS=$'\t' path=anyregex
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work on my examples -  my old name didn't appear in the list. I think I'd need to bump the renameLimit up pretty high to hit these old renames. I can see how it would help for smaller repos, though!

Comment: The rename limit is per-commit, haven't checked but  you could try adding `-M100%` to only find the pure ones, I'm guessing a move that big was done separately?

Answer (score 0):

If a file were created:

```bash
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m 'add file'
```

...And later, renamed:

```bash
$ mv a b
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'rename file'
```

You could find the "rename" commit like this:

```bash
$ git log --oneline -- a
bbbbbbb rename file
aaaaaaa add file
```

...And show the changes:

```bash
$ git show bbbbbbb
...
diff --git a/a b/b
similarity index 100%
rename from a
rename to b
```

Comment: `git log -- a` won’t show the rename stat or any stat info (at least with my Git config).

Comment: I think this is exactly the procedure I mentioned in the description, right?

Comment: @dbn I'm sorry, I hadn't noticed. The last commit that modifies `a` should be the one that renamed it, so a `git show` can tell you the new filename